# Dependency specified was System.IO >= 4.1.0 but ended up with System.IO 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a .NET core project , the project.json looks like

```
{
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "System.IO": "4.1.0",
    "System.Net.Http": "4.1.0",
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }

  },
  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0-*"
}
```

When I build I get the following warning

```
warning NU1007: Dependency specified was System.IO >= 4.1.0 but ended up with System.IO 4.3.0-preview1-24530-04.
```

I don't want to upgrade `System.IO` to a preview build as this code is ready to ship and all the testing has been carried with the current `project.json`. Can I force version 4.1.0?

Comment: There appears to be no way to force an *exact* version in a `project.json`. You could try asking for `4.1.*`, which should restrict things to the 4.1 branch at least (which is still not exact, but should not go to a preview version of 4.3).

Comment: Can you just tell it to ignore previews? Thanks

Comment: Am I worrying about this too much? Forcing 4.1.* creates other warnings as other References are expecting preview version and its not a case of preview expecting preview. Version 1.0.1 of EF is expecting many 4.3 preview versions of System.* dlls.

Comment: have you run dotnet restore?

Comment: restore from VS works, restore from command line fails `Unable to resolve 'OneOfMyProjects (>= 1.0.0)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.` I guess this is a different issue :) I can build and publish and the published version works etc.

Comment: @ChrisHawkes fell free to write this up as the Answer.. or if you wish I can. I am still having dotnet restore issues but this is not related.

Answer (score 1):

Execute the following command at the project or solution level:

```
dotnet restore --no-cache
```

If this won't help, then delete the corresponding package folder:

```
%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages\System.IO
```

and try `dotnet restore` again.

Comment: useful info, the question has been answered with one of @ChrisHawkes  comments. Specifying version as 4.1.* will force it to keep on the 4.1.* branch which is good enough.

Comment: @SteveDrake, it resolved your issue just because it has some side effects, one of which restarted the process of package restore and you received the required version as a result. Anyway, i you don't need a specific version, then you may go with "4.1.*". If you need a specific version, you should state it as "4.1.0". And use `dotnet restore` after modifying `project.json`.